# Scales in Scene View but not Game View

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

https://imgur.com/a/v9z7h4F - video so you can see what's happening.

want the items that I pick up to change from their original size to about 6" by the time they reach my hand, I seem to have done that part no problem, in the editor if the item is picked up it shrinks as it moves to my hand.

however, in game view, through the headset camera, the item does not shrink to fit in your hand, it stays full size. what would be causing it to behave properly in editor screen but not in game screen?

the code is done to change the size by the percentage it moves between its starting point and the player point, so theoretically in the video clip attached (game screen is the bottom screen) the object should visually stay the same size but be moving closer, instead its actually staying the same size so visually getting larger as it gets closer. when you look at the top screen its obviously getting much smaller as it gets closer to the player, that is the desired effect.

don't know if it being VR actually has anything to do with this.

some more info, even though I don't think its relevant: developing for Meta Quest, the resize script is attached to the object itself and activated when object is selected by the ray interactor, player doesn't have any ability to move other than physical movement.

when you grab the item in scene view and drag it using its transform it actually behaves on both screens as expected. but when picked up in game by the Ray Interactor that is when it works in scene view but not game view.

here is another video to better show that aspect. https://imgur.com/a/pQHdDBn you can see when the ray interactor picks up the chair the mesh collider doesnt shrink with the chair either, but when pucked up by the transform with the mouse it all shrinks on both screens

```
public class ResizeObject : XRGrabInteractable
{
    private Vector3 OriginalSize;
    private float BiggestDimention;
    private float OriginalDistance;
    private float TargetScale;
    private Vector3 OriginalPos;
    private Vector3 OriginalRot;
    private Vector3 OriginalScale;

    public bool selected;
    private readonly float targetSize = .15f;
    private Vector3 playerPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        selected = false;

        playerPos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position;

        OriginalPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        OriginalRot = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, transform.rotation.z);
        OriginalScale = transform.localScale;

        OriginalSize = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.size;
        BiggestDimention = OriginalSize.x;
        if (OriginalSize.y > BiggestDimention)
            BiggestDimention = OriginalSize.y;
        if (OriginalSize.z > BiggestDimention)
            BiggestDimention = OriginalSize.z;

        TargetScale = targetSize / BiggestDimention;

        OriginalDistance = Vector3.Distance(OriginalPos, playerPos);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (selected)
        {
            float currentScale = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) / OriginalDistance;
            if (currentScale > 1)
                currentScale = 1;
            else if (currentScale < TargetScale)
                currentScale = TargetScale;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(currentScale,currentScale,currentScale);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSelectEntered(SelectEnterEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnSelectEntered(args);
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Select()");
        selected = true;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(TargetScale,TargetScale,TargetScale);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectExited(SelectExitEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnSelectExited(args);
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Deselect()");
        selected = false;
        transform.position = OriginalPos;
        transform.eulerAngles = OriginalRot;
        transform.localScale = OriginalScale;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like the `XRGrabInteractable` does it's own magic internally when triggered through the ray interaction.

If you look into the code you can find that on three places it does

> ```
> transform.localScale = m_TargetLocalScale;
> ```

in methods that are related to the interaction update (`PerformInstantaneousUpdate`, `PerformKinematicUpdate`, `PerformVelocityTrackingUpdate`)

This value is set in `Grab`

> ```
> m_TargetLocalScale = thisTransform.localScale;
> ```

and in `UpdateTarget`

> ```
> InvokeGrabTransformersProcess(updatePhase, ref rawTargetPose, ref m_TargetLocalScale);
> ```

None of these are `virtual` - except `ProcessInteractable` which is calling those three `PerformXYUpdate` methods above) so you could try and simply overwrite the scale when it is done

```
public override void ProcessInteractable(XRInteractionUpdateOrder.UpdatePhase updatePhase)
{
    base.ProcessInteractable(updatePhase);

    var currentScale = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) / OriginalDistance;
    currentScale = Mathf.Clamp(currentScale, TargetScale, 1f);
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one * currentScale;
}
```

unfortunately the `m_TargetLocalScale` and places where it is updated are all `private` / not `virtual` so if you really were to change that one directly you would need to go through reflection (which you should avoid if possible)

```
private static FieldInfo targetScaleField = typeof(XRGrabInteractable).GetField("m_TargetLocalScale", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

public override void ProcessInteractable(XRInteractionUpdateOrder.UpdatePhase updatePhase)
{
    var currentScale = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerPos) / OriginalDistance;
    currentScale = Mathf.Clamp(currentScale, TargetScale, 1f);
    
    targetScaleField.SetValue(this, Vector3.one * currentScale);
    
    base.ProcessInteractable(updatePhase);
}
```

Note though that the methods internally use `ref m_TargetLocalScale` so they might even overwrite the value again before it is applied so there is no guarantee this works as expected either.

---

Some more side notes

- I would btw basically everything that is in your `Start` move into the `OnSelectEntered` so you initialize the values in that moment - in particular because your player will probably move around so initializing those only once in `Start` yields invalid results.
- `transform.rotation` is a `Quaternion`! It has 4 components. You are using it like euler angles in

  ```
  OriginalRot = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, transform.rotation.z);
  ```

  which is completely invalid! Rather store and apply the rotation directly as `Quaternion`. You **never** want to touch the components of a `Quaternion` directly (unless you really really know what you are doing)
- Both `Quaternion` and `Vector3` are `struct` -> value types which are always stored and passed as a **copy**

  => Instead of things like

  ```
  OriginalPos = new Vectro3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
  ```

  you can rather simply write

  ```
  OriginalPos = transform.position;
  ```
- For the `BiggestDimention` (it is "dimension" btw) there is a built-in extension method that comes shipped along with the `Unity.XR.CoreUtils` you have installed as a dependency of the XR Interaction Toolkit anyway

  ```
  BiggestDimention = OriginalSize.MaxComponent();
  ```

Comment: i was looking all through the ray interactor, never looked through the grab interactable code. i will read this a few times and see if i can figure it out and get back to you on that

it is "dimension" btw   ---- thank you for this, i dont know why i didnt see it, i blame tab fill haha, i hate when i have typos in my code but at least with tabfill it still works.

i should have figured there would be a MaxComponent() of some sort, thank you.

the quaternion thing i also should have realized and will definitely be changing that but it did seem to work despite that.

Comment: and normally i wouldnt put the player position in Start() but the player has no way of moving around, well, i suppose i cant really stop them from physically moving so maybe it would be better to grab the current position

Comment: public override void ProcessInteractable worked, I am so happy, now that its working ill go through and refine it into better code, i screwed it all up trying to figure this out haha. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: @GillmoreGames glad that it worked and brought you forward! You never stop learning so no worries, I also learn new things every day just by answering questions :'D